# Remove recent texts from phone contact screen

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Nexus 6 Android 6.0.1. Somehow I managed to turn on a function that displays my most recent texts when I access the contact screen. I don't want that info displaying every time I access a contact. How do I turn it off? Thanks in advance folks!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you mean the text itself or information like when the text was received/sent?

Comment: The text itself. When I bring up my contacts (say, to make a call) and pick one, it lists the last couple of texts underneath their name and number.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the fix. Settings -> Apps & notifications -> App permissions -> SMS permissions.  Remove permission for it to access Contacts.  It's kind of backward thinking.  It looks like the Messaging app (default on my Pixel) was posting my recent text activity to the Contacts app.  My phone history is still listed under each contact as most apps do.